# Retornar nome da coluna baseado no valor da célula

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Dado o dataframe:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando retornar o nome de uma coluna baseado no valor da coluna **mais vende**

Exemplo:

- No **index 0** e na coluna **mais_vende**: *Palito de dentes*, quero retornar o nome da coluna **vende_palito**
- No **index 1** e na coluna **mais_vende**: *Leite*, quero retornar o nome da coluna **vende_leite**

Tentei usar o  `loc` e o `np.where` para resolver o problema e não estou conseguindo nem chegar perto do resultado desejado.

Dados do Dataframe(*Criado usando o Pandas e o Numpy*)

`data = {'vende_palito': ['Palito de Dentes', np.nan], 'vende_tomate': ['Tomate', 'Tomate'], 'vende_fosforo': [np.nan,'Fósforo'], 'vende_leite': ['Leite', 'Leite'], 'mais_vende': ['Palito de Dentes', 'Leite']}`

`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

Resultado desejado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Veja se ajuda: `s1= df.iloc[:,0:4].isin(df['mais_vende']).any()` e `print(s1[s1].index)`

Comment: Muito obrigado @AugustoVasques consigo chegar no resultado usando isso também, acho que não fui muito claro em explicar o que eu queria fazer. Mas consigo usar seu exemplo também! Valeu!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

se entendi direito voce quer alterar o valor das celulas de uma coluna especifia, nesse caso acho que com '.apply()' pode quebrar sempre um galho, ja que permite iterar o df em uma funcao personalidada.

```
def coluna_celula(celula:str) -> str:
    primeira_palavra = celula.split()[0].lower()
    str_alterada = 'vende_' + primeira_palavra
    return str_alterada

df['resultado'] = df.mais_vende.apply(coluna_celula)
```

pode ser que funcione tbm - e de maneira mais eficiente -  pd.Series.srt.replace(regex=True) mas ai precisa elaborar o padrao